# How to fix "Access to the path is denied" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, directory

I have a folder and I want to some process in this folder like unzip and read a file. It's perfect this part but I have an error like that when the try open the folder on asp.net:

```
 Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
    \\101.101.101.126\d$\abc\abc\abc' is denied. 
         at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
         String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String
     userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, 
         Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption) at 
         System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, 
         String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) at GetEmailReport.GetEmailCampaignDeliveryStatusReportViaFtp() in
          c:\abc\abc\abc.cs:line 120
```

I changed folder permission for `ISS` user ,Asp.Net and others but I have some err. How to fix this error?

Comment: Do you have admin access to that computer? (you need it for access to d$) When you open directory \\101.101.101.126\d$\abc\abc\abc from windows explorer, you get error, or you see files? Can you paste here part of your code (not error) close to line 120, how to you use GetFiles? Try you a different approach .. like access to named share like \\101.101.101.126\incom (if there is any). And what operating system do you use?

Comment: my code works my local machine but when i add server , i have this error.

Comment: you can not access server this way (\\101.101.101.126\d$). this type of share (admin share) is only for windows folder sharing in local network. If ISS in your text is shortcut for Internet Information Services from Microsoft then use IIS instead and use it as tag also. I dont know much about IIS.

Answer (score 0):

The user, whose account is used to run your application, must have access to that path

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Configure a special application pool for your application, that will run under a user that has necessary permissions (can access admin shares on remote server). So your entire application will run under that account and have all its permissions.
2. Using impersonation to execute parts of your code under another account. This doesn't require any IIS configuration and is more secure and flexible than first way (for example? you can impersonate several accounts in a single application).

I use a helper class for this purpose: http://pastebin.com/HQWT7yFX (can't find original author, so this is my slightly modified version)